# Confusion Matrix doesn't show correct count of actual values. Multinomial regression, factors

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, multinomial

I have two vectors, actual and predicted values. Both are factor type with 8 levels. The 8th level has only 55 observations in actual, and 0 in predicted. However, when I make a confusion matrix the level 8 observations disappear or are moved somehow. Shouldn't the columns of actual sum to their actual counts?

I made confusion matrices two different ways to double check. I also tried explicitly making the factor levels the same in both vectors. No luck so far.

```
library(nnet); library(caret)

sc <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00272/SkillCraft1_Dataset.csv")

# First column is ID
sc$LeagueIndex <- as.factor(sc$LeagueIndex)
sc <- sc[, -1]

# Set missing values to NA
which_qm <- sc[, c(2,3,4)] == '?'
sc[, c(2,3,4)][which_qm] <- NA
sc[, c(2,3,4)] <- apply(sc[, c(2,3,4)], 2, as.numeric)

# Set impossible values to NA
sc$TotalHours[sc$Age < sc$TotalHours/8760] <- NA
sc$HoursPerWeek[sc$HoursPerWeek >= 168] <- NA

# Fit model and store predictions
sc_mod1 <- multinom(LeagueIndex ~ ., sc)
sc_fitted1 <- predict(sc_mod1, sc)

# sc_fitted1 is missing factor level 8
confusionMatrix(data = sc_fitted1, reference = sc$LeagueIndex)
table(predicted = sc_fitted1, actual = sc$LeagueIndex)

# sc_fitted1 has factor level 8
levels(sc_fitted1) <- levels(sc$LeagueIndex)
confusionMatrix(data = sc_fitted1, reference = sc$LeagueIndex)
table(predicted = sc_fitted1, actual = sc$LeagueIndex)

# What's the problem?
table(sc$LeagueIndex)
length(sc$LeagueIndex)

table(sc_fitted1)
length(sc_fitted1)
```

Comment: I think there just aren't any predictions that come out as 8, so `table` skips row 8. I have produced tables from predicted vs actual classifications that regularly skip intermediate values if there are no predictions in that category, so I think this is just normal `table` behavior - you have to specify the factor levels directly (like what you do down below) for all the rows and columns with zeroes to show up. Also, thank you for making this problem easily reproducible! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the NA values you produce and they are all for level 8 of your target variable. You'll probably have to find another way to code those NAs, if you want level 8 to be taken into account.

Try this as a counter example:

```
library(nnet); library(caret)

sc <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00272/SkillCraft1_Dataset.csv")

sc$LeagueIndex <- as.factor(sc$LeagueIndex)
sc <- sc[, -1]

which_qm <- sc[, c(2,3,4)] == '?'
sc[, c(2,3,4)][which_qm] <- 20   # this is just a random numeric value (not the best one to use!)
sc[, c(2,3,4)] <- apply(sc[, c(2,3,4)], 2, as.numeric)

sc_mod1 <- multinom(LeagueIndex ~ ., sc)
sc_fitted1 <- predict(sc_mod1, sc)

confusionMatrix(data = sc_fitted1, reference = sc$LeagueIndex)
table(predicted = sc_fitted1, actual = sc$LeagueIndex)
```

It will give you something like this:

```
         actual
predicted   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
        1  52  30   9   2   0   0   0   0
        2  61 123  78  58   4   1   0   0
        3  30  77 142  79  23   4   0   0
        4  21 104 248 410 252  45   0   0
        5   2  11  60 217 343 230   1   0
        6   1   2  16  45 184 333  32   2
        7   0   0   0   0   0   5   2   0
        8   0   0   0   0   0   3   0  53
```